# How to render multiple values of node reference in the form of an ordered list without views?

Tags: nodes

I have a node reference field that references another node and has multiple values. I want to get an ordered list of the output of that field and display it in the custom node template. I am rendering the node reference as a cck block. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In D6, you could do something like this:

```
print '<ol>';
foreach ($node->field_whatever as $foo) {
  print '<li>';
    $bar=node_load($foo['nid']);
    print l($bar->title, 'node/' . $bar->nid);
  print '</li>';
}
print '</ol>';
```

In D7 you'd have to throw in the node language stuff and there might even be something more exciting built in as well but I think they all use divs instead of lists.  (In both you could also create a content field template for this instead of hardcoding it in your node template)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the [Text List Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/textformatter) module will do what you want.

> This module provides a field display formatter to render field values as HTML or comma-separated lists. This can currently be used on all core field types (text, long text, number, list, and taxonomy reference etc..) and some contributed fields. (see below).
>
> For multi-value fields, each field value becomes a list item. For long text fields, each line becomes a list item.